# Calculating the Modular Inverse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, rsa, inverse, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to take ed = 1 mod((p-1)(q-1)) and solve for d, just like the RSA algorithm.

e = 5, (p-1)*(q-1) = 249996

I've tried a lot of code in javascript such as:

```
function modInverse(){
var e = 5;
var p = 499;
var q = 503;
var d = e.modInverse((p-1) * (q-1));
DisplayResult(d, "privateKeyResultLabel")
}
```

or

```
function modInverse(){ 
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(5).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(249996)));
}
```

I just can't figure out the correct way to solve for d, the modular inverse, in javascript.

Comment: `System.out.println`? That's Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Embarassing... I'm really new to coding. I need it for javascript not java then! I know there is a modInverse() function is javascript. I just dont know how to properly use it.

Comment: How do you know there is a `modInverse()` in JavaScript? Because I'm pretty sure there isn't a built-in function for that.

Comment: No, there is certainly no built-in function for that (JavaScript's standard library is quite minimal). You might find libraries built by others which have such a function, but definitely not in the browser itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just going through the definition of [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) and from what I understand:

```
ax = 1 (mod m)
=> m is a divisor of ax -1 and x is the inverse we are looking for
=> ax - 1 = q*m (where q is some integer)
And the most important thing is gcd(a, m) = 1
i.e. a and m are co-primes
```

In your case:

```
ed = 1 mod((p-1)(q-1)) //p, q and e are given 
=> ed - 1 = z*((p-1)(q-1)) //where z is some integer and we need to find d
```

Again from the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), one can compute the modular inverse using the [extended Euclidean GCD Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm) which does the following:

```
ax + by = g //where g = gcd(a,b) i.e. a and b are co-primes
//The extended gcd algorithm gives us the value of x and y as well.
```

In your case the equation would be something like this:

```
ed - z*((p-1)(q-1)) = 1; //Compare it with the structure given above

a -> e
x -> d
b -> (p-1)(q-1)
y -> z
```

So if we just apply that algorithm to this case, we will get the values of `d` and `z`.

For `ax + by = gcd(a,b)`, the extended gcd algorithm could look something like ([source](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/%7Ecazelais/euclid.html)):

```
function xgcd(a, b) { 

  if (b == 0) {
    return [1, 0, a];
  }

  temp = xgcd(b, a % b);
  x = temp[0];
  y = temp[1];
  d = temp[2];
  return [y, x-y*Math.floor(a/b), d];
}
```

> This algorithm runs in time **O(log(m)^2)**, assuming |a| < m, and is generally more efficient than exponentiation.

I don't know if there is an inbuilt function for this in javascript. I doubt if there is, and I am a fan of algorithms, so I thought you might want to give this approach a try. You can fiddle with it and change it to handle your range of values and I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: You can implement the extended GCD without recursion so it would run in constant space.

Comment: thank you so much. i knew the code would have something to do with the extended euclidean alg. i wasn't sure how to store the values. good call on the array!

Answer (score 8):

This implementation of modular inverse can accept any type of inputs. If input types are not supported, `NaN` is returned. Also, it does not use recursion.

```js
function modInverse(a, m) {
  // validate inputs
  [a, m] = [Number(a), Number(m)]
  if (Number.isNaN(a) || Number.isNaN(m)) {
    return NaN // invalid input
  }
  a = (a % m + m) % m
  if (!a || m < 2) {
    return NaN // invalid input
  }
  // find the gcd
  const s = []
  let b = m
  while(b) {
    [a, b] = [b, a % b]
    s.push({a, b})
  }
  if (a !== 1) {
    return NaN // inverse does not exists
  }
  // find the inverse
  let x = 1
  let y = 0
  for(let i = s.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    [x, y] = [y,  x - y * Math.floor(s[i].a / s[i].b)]
  }
  return (y % m + m) % m
}

// Tests
console.log(modInverse(1, 2))       // = 1
console.log(modInverse(3, 6))       // = NaN
console.log(modInverse(25, 87))     // = 7
console.log(modInverse(7, 87))      // = 25
console.log(modInverse(19, 1212393831))     // = 701912218
console.log(modInverse(31, 73714876143))    // = 45180085378
console.log(modInverse(3, 73714876143))     // = NaN
console.log(modInverse(-7, 87))     // = 62
console.log(modInverse(-25, 87))    // = 80
console.log(modInverse(0, 3))       // = NaN
console.log(modInverse(0, 0))       // = NaN
```